# strange behavior in PHP temp var

Tags: php

```
foreach ($arr1 as $v){
 ...
}

foreach ($arr2 as $v){
 ...
}
```

then, the two `$v` will have some strange behavior. If i replace the second `$v` with `$v2`, then everything is ok.

Comment: define: strange behavior

Comment: You would get strange behaviour if the first loop was using a reference e.g. `foreach ($arr1 as &$v) {} ` - the last item in `$arr2` would be set to each item of `$arr1` in turn.

Comment: Its pretty amazing how a so poorly made question gets so many *probably good* answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not nesting the loops, try `unset()`ting `$v` just after the first foreach loop and before the second foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Any 'strange behaviour' that is happening is probably because you are nesting the foreach loops, so you *will* need to change the var name of the second exposed `$v` as the first `$v` will be available within the scope of the second (nested) foreach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like

```
foreach($arr1 as $v
{
    foreach($arr2 as $v)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

I could see an issue. Otherwise we need a better definition of "strange behavior."

Answer (score -1):

In the case of

```
foreach ($arr1 as $v) {
    // some code ...
    foreach ($arr2 as $v) {
        // more code
    }
    // here you might see something unexpected, namely the last $v of the inner loop, not the current $v of the outer loop
}
```

However, if you have the two `foreach` loops one after the other, not nested, I can't imagine what strange behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Don't copy other people's answers.

Comment: @nikic: It bears a **very** strong resemblance to my answer.

Comment: There is something of a resemblance, but with a some explanation of exactly what "strange behaviour" might happen where. *shrug*

Comment: Your answer was the third: mine was the fourth. The first two answers also mention nested `foreach` loops, and are essentially the same as yours. You just added a minimalist code sample, which the first two didn't.